# peresent UIAlertController from UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode

I didn't succeed to perform UIAlertController from UITableViewCell

I have already tried to create a segue programmatically and then perform it(code num 1), but it crash at appDelegate (the crash happened at appDelegate)
I tried to use code 2 and it did nothing(that printed :" whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" maybe it connected?),
I tried to call function in viewController.Swift to present and/or segue and it didn't succeed as well

the alert should appear  only when a specific button in a cell is pressed

code 1:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

code 2:

```
var segue = UIStoryboardSegue.init(identifier: "goAlart", source: ViewController(), destination: refreshAlert)

segue.perform()
```

the exception that I got at appDelegate is: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
when I delete "segue.perform()" I got no errors

Comment: you might want to present the uialert from [didSelectRow at](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) method?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard file to create your controllers? or you are not using IB?

Comment: I have a storyboard but I create the alert proggramaticly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In "tableViewCell.swift," put:

```
weak var delegate:yourViewController!
```

and then you have access to all variables from `viewController` and all features, like:

```
present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And, in "cellForRowAt indexPath," put:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as my solution above? Just without a protocol

Comment: Hey, I was searching for a solution and came across this answer. I got the delegate to use the present func - delegate.present(UIViewControllwer, animated: Bool). Its taking the delegate of the UITableViewController class. But then the app crashes on that same line saying: Found nil while unwrapping an optional. How do I get around that issue? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, good place to show the alert would be `didSelectRow at`. 
I can't see the rest of the code, but I assume you have your **UIAlertController** initialised and property `refreshAlert` point's to it. If `refreshAlert` is stored in `ViewController`, then this should work:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

**EDIT:**
Since you need to show the alert on button press in cell, good way to do so, would be a delegate protocol:

```
protocol MyCusomCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
  func didPressAlertButton()
}
```

In your cell, you declare delegate property:

```
  weak var delegate: MyCusomCellDelegate?
```

On pressing the button, you call delegate method:

```
delegate?.didPressAlertButton()
```

In ViewController you conform to the protocol:

```
extension ViewController: MyCusomCellDelegate {
  func didPressAlertButton() {
    present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

And lastly, in `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
cell.delegate = self
```

if you need to show different alert for different cells, then you should pass some data in the delegate call.

Comment: I use the alert only when a specific button in a cell is pressed so it wouldn't help thanks anyway

Comment: I updated the answer to work with button instead of selecting a cell